# Angular2 With ASP.NET WebAPI2 Controller sending blank content back

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-services

Ok I'm really confused about this one. I have a angular2 app and it successfully does a `http GET` request to my localhost server. I implement a return type of `IHttpActionResult` with a return status of `Ok` and send some content back but when I look at the response on my console the content is blank but ti is retrieving the appropriate status code ie(`200 ok`). I need to find a way to send back json to my andular2 service.

Below is my WebAPI2 controller:

```
[Route("api/login")]
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Login()
    {
        //return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, Json(new { success = true }));
        //return Json(new { success = true });
        List<int> myValues = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        return Ok(myValues);
    }
}
```

My angular2 Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    isLoggedIn = false;
    private _url = "http://localhost:61333/";
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

login(login) {
    return this._http.get(this._url + "api/login").map(res => res.json());
}

logout() {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
}
}
```

And my angular2 component that is invoking my login function in my service

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

// Services
import { AuthService } from '../../_services/auth.service';

// Models
import { Login } from '../../_models/login.class';

@Component({
    styles: [require('./login.component.css')],
    template: require('./login.component.html')
    //providers: [AuthService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginObj = new Login();
    constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router) {
    }

login(form) {
    this.loginObj.email = form.form._value.email;
    this.loginObj.password = form.form._value.password;

    this._authService.login(this.loginObj).subscribe(
        value => {  console.log("SUC:" + value); }
    );
}

}
```

Thanks you.
Ross

Comment: You could check with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), if your API actually returns something. Other than that, I can't see any errors in your code.

Comment: I changed the url to use `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` and it returns json successfully